# Do Biblical Unitarians believe that Christians can pray to Jesus and, if so, that he can answer a prayer in which he is asked about his divinity?

Tags: christology, prayer, divinity, christophany, biblical-unitarian

I personally believe that there are biblical grounds for praying to Jesus (e.g. [this](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/59017/38524) and [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/62358/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-praying-to-jesus-as-opposed-to-praying-to-god-in)), and, as far as I'm aware, many Christians believe the same. However, I'm currently in ignorance with regards to the Biblical Unitarian position on the subject.

I have four questions:

1. Do Biblical Unitarians believe that praying to Jesus is a legitimate, scriptural practice?
2. If the answer to the previous question is yes: do they also believe that Jesus can answer questions verbally (as in [Acts 9:10-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+9%3A10-16&version=ESV) and [2 Cor 12:8-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Cor+12%3A8-9&version=ESV))?
3. If the answer to the previous question is yes: do they believe then that if one prays to Jesus and asks him if he is God, he will respond with an unambiguous answer?
4. If the answer to the previous question is yes: has a Biblical Unitarian ever done this?

Comment: what is praying? Saying 'thank you Jesus' - is that praying? Of course it is. Why wouldn't this be normal for a Christian to acknowledge his life and victory? God's word is quite clear on who Jesus is - the prayer is already answered!

Comment: @user47952 - *"the prayer is already answered!"* - Really? And what is the answer (in a few words)?

Comment: Unfortunately, 2 Timothy 4:3-4  has been true for some time - about 2000 years! (and 3:7)

Comment: The first one is pretty easy to answer. Why do you think there will be an answer to 2.-4. that is a Biblical Unitarian answer, though?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - why wouldn't there be?

Comment: Is there a specifically Biblical Unitarian interpretation of 2 Cor 12:8-9? I don't think so - did Jesus literally, verbally say something to Paul? Was it rather a definite sense which Paul translated into words? I don't know. Similarly, why would a Biblical Unitarian have a specific answer on whether Jesus would respond to a specific prayer with an unambiguous, verbal answer? Similarly, 4. is an empirical question, no?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - (1) What about Acts 9:10-16 (question edited btw)? (2) If I were an expert on what BUs believe, I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place. (3) What's wrong with asking an empirical question?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator My apologies - given the questions you've asked before about Biblical Unitarianism, I thought you would know that Biblical Unitarians are mostly united on 1 issue - that God is the Father, not Jesus. After that, there are all sorts of differences (as there are differences among Trinitarians on all sorts of issues). I don't see any reason why a Biblical Unitarian would think Jesus couldn't communicate verbally to someone. Whether someone's verbal experience is veridical is another question, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biblical Unitarians have a wide range of views about a wide range of subjects - the term simply groups together people who believe God is the Father, not Jesus, and also hold that the Bible has authority in a strong sense (as opposed to other forms of Unitarianism which view the Bible as having authority in a weaker sense). Biblical Unitarians are a faction within Christianity, not a specific denomination.

Question 1. is highly relevant to the defining features of Biblical Unitarianism. If Jesus is not God, is it OK to pray to him?

The answer commonly seems to be yes, but there is debate.

The article *[Can We "Pray" to Jesus Christ?](https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/jesus-christ/can-we-pray-to-jesus-christ)* from BiblicalUnitarian.com addresses this question.

> "There is a controversy among Christians who believe that Jesus is not
> God but the Son of God, about whether or not we can pray to Jesus. The
> only definitive place to go for an answer to that question is the Word
> of God. [...] We believe that the Bible makes it clear that one can
> pray to Jesus, but does not have to, and we will do our best to show
> why that is."

This is perhaps similar to the debate between Protestants and Catholics about whether praying 'to' Saints is OK. Different people have different views.

In particular, Jesus seems to say we can ask Him for things. John 14:14

> "You may ask me for anything in my name, and I will do it."

However, there is debate about whether this means addressing the prayer to Jesus, or addressing the prayer to God in Jesus' name, which Jesus unambiguously says we can do.

So the answer to 1. is 'yes' for at least some Biblical Unitarians. Even there, though, the emphasis is perhaps different from standard Trinitarian practise.

> "Those who enthusiastically embrace the idea of praying to the Lord
> Jesus must recognize that this practice **ought not to be carried out to
> the point of distracting one from the worship of the Father**. We are
> sure that the Lord Jesus would find it ironic indeed if he himself
> were to become the principal object of Christian worship and
> adoration, when his entire life and ministry was devoted to the
> glorification of his Father."

For question 2., as the OP points out, there are instances in scripture where people seem to 'hear' Jesus. Since that's the case, I don't see why Biblical Unitarians would object to this idea.

Question 3. moves away from something specific to Biblical Unitarianism, presumably a prayer could be answered unambiguously.

Question 4. is an empirical question, but really two questions. Has someone had an experience like this? Were they having a veridical experience? I'm sure a Biblical Unitarian has done this, but I don't have a link to reports of this.

Comment: Question out of curiosity: what would convince a Biblical Unitarian that Jesus is God? Because based on your answers to questions 3 and 4, it looks like not even a Christophany would do it.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Would a Biblical Unitarian apparently receiving an answer from God in prayer that Jesus is not God convince a typical Trinitarian?

Comment: Do you mean the Biblical Unitarian receives the revelation and then he/she shares their testimony with the Trinitarian, or the Trinitarian receives the revelation directly? The former would a second-hand story from the Trinitarian's viewpoint, whereas the latter would be an undeniable first-hand experience. Therefore, I would say that the latter would be more compelling to the Trinitarian than the former.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Oh, you mean if a Biblical Unitarian himself received a Christophany where Jesus claims to be God?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to say in the question (my apologies if I explained myself very poorly) - update: question edited

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you're saying. I'm sure a Biblical Unitarian has prayed to God or Jesus and asked for clarification re Jesus, but I don't have documented cases I can link to.

Comment: If someone who believed God was a turnip and received confirmation in prayer (audible or not) that yes, God is a turnip, it is possible that the God prayed to was no God at all but something else altogether.  "Lord, Lord we did all this stuff in your name."  "I never knew you."  If Jesus is not gotten right there is grave danger.

Comment: @MikeBorden I can't follow the logic or relevance here - re-try, maybe? You think conceiving of God as the Father and not in trinitarian terms is equivalent to believing God is a turnip?

Comment: I merely mean that whatever is, is.  One's God is triune and another's is not.  They may both be wrong but they cannot both be right.  If God is not triune then the confirmations that a trinitarian receives in spirit, study, and prayer are not from God but from elsewhere.

Comment: @MikeBorden Why do you think that? I can have a significantly incorrect concept of 'Mike Borden', but Mike Borden can still tell me all sorts of things that are true. No?

Comment: But can you hear those things?  What if the true things I tell you contradict the concept of 'Mike Borden' that you hold?  If I am convinced God is triune but He is not, can I hear Him telling me so?  Or, if God is triune, can one actually receive confirmation from Him that He is not.  Jesus did not say that everyone has ears but rather "He who has ears, let him hear".

Comment: Why do I think that?  If God is not triune then He would never reveal Himself as a trinity because that would be a lie.

Comment: @MikeBorden "If God is not triune then He would never reveal Himself as a trinity because that would be a lie" Right, and if He wasn't, He would not 'reveal' that either. You can make the same argument about all kinds of doctrines, no? Some people are wrong, and so any inspiration for those is in some way incorrect, whatever the ultimate analysis of the error.